# How to mute a specific window using Python?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to use this in one of my projects. I ended up with pyaudio and pycaw. But they both had some errors and both didn't work out. Is there an alternate way to mute a specific window?

When I was trying pyaudio, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\newscript.py", line 75, in <module>
    sd.set_stream_volume(audio_output_stream, 0.0)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'sounddevice' has no attribute 'set_stream_volume'
```

And when I was trying pycaw, I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\newscript.py", line 67, in <module>
    apps = pycaw.get_applications()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pycaw' has no attribute 'get_applications'
```